# How to execute code when Universal Windows Store App is closing?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am developing an app for Windows 10 Store app, but I can't seem to find/learn on how to check if the user pressed the red close button (at the top right) or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. Basically what I want is something like this:

```
private void app_Close(object sender, CloseEventArgs e)
{
     //saves some data in the app :D
}
```

Comment: The fact that the method gets called is a good indication that they have clicked the close button, isn't it?

Comment: What do you want to do differently? The two actions are supposed to be identical for the user.

Comment: Are you building an App for the Windows Store or Win32/ WPF?

Comment: I would suggest maybe changing your question title from "How to check if the user press the red close button or Alt+F4" to something more direct along the lines of "How to execute code when win universal app is closing". That might gather more knowledgeable people in the task you're looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## .: EDIT :.

If you have a Universal app that doesn't have a MainWindow object you'll probably want to tap into the "Suspending" event:

```
appObject.Suspending += (s, a) =>
        {
            SaveTheData(); // I really like my data and want it for later too
        };
```

or

```
public App()
    {
    /*
        stuff
     */
    Suspending += (s, a) =>
        {
            SaveTheData(); // I really like my data and want it for later too
        };
    }
```

## .: Original :.

Add a handler to your MainWindow "Closing" event to save your data. Once "Closing" has finished, "Close" should fire normally.

```
theMainWindowObject.Closing += (s,a) =>
    {
        SaveTheData(); // It's precious!
    };
```

I have something similar to this in one of my smaller applications where in the constructor for MainWindow I put the above snippet substituting "theMainWindowObject" for "this" so that it references itself

So I have:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
    // Note: "this." isn't necessary here but it helps me with mental accounting
    this.Closing += (s, a) =>
        {
            Save();
        };
    }
```

If you're just saving one or two properties and don't have any crazy logic going on you can just drop it right in the handler:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
    Closing += (s, a) =>
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsPopupX = mySettingsPopupObject.GetX();
            Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsPopupY = mySettingsPopupObject.GetY();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        };
    }
```

Comment: Hi Dragon, thanks for your time, but I am developing a Universal Windows Store app, and `Closing` event does not seem to be exist, I guess..

Comment: Ut oh, I've not written any Universal Windows Store apps so I'm not sure how that effects things. Is there an "OnClosing()" method group you can access for your main window object?

Comment: Dragon, no, it seems there is no "OnClosing()" method too.. I just want to save the data when the user manually close the app.. guess I have to save the data everytime the user key in a data..

Comment: Editted! Read the bottom section and hopefully that helps you!

Comment: Hi Dragon, thanks for your time! But it is not working.. never mind, I will use my way to save the data.. :D

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wish I could have helped! Hopefully someone who knows more about it will come along and be more helpful to you! Good luck!

Comment: @rydev  What was your way to save the data?

Comment: @Felix , I don't do UWP development anymore so I am sorry if I can't help you, but as far as I remembered,  `App.xaml.cs` contains the function `OnSuspending`, you can save the data before `deferral.Complete();`.. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage your Application Lifecycle have a look at this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt243287.aspx
In general you don't have a "close" event in Windows Apps. Your App will be suspended when Windows or your user wants to close it. Using the `ApplicationExecutionState` [(see more)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.applicationexecutionstate.aspx) enum you can find out who (windows or your user) closed the app.

Hope it helps!